# Audio Stopped when bluetooth disconnected during OpenTok session

Tags: ios, core-audio, opentok

I am new in implementing OpenTok framework in iOS application. When bluetooth is connected while running OpenTok session both subscriber and publishers are listened to each other but during session if bluetooth is disconnected from native iOS settings.Audio does not route automatically to speaker and communication is stopped between publisher and subscriber.

OpentTok IOS SDK version 2.18.1

IOS version : 14.2

Comment: Hi, I cloned our sample project (https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift) and tried disconnecting Bluetooth from the control center and from the settings app (after enabling background audio) and the project still works. A few questions:

+ When you say communication is stopped, do you mean there is no audio or the delegate functions fire and disconnect the app?

+ Do you have background modes enabled? 

+ Are you doing any additional AVAudioSession handling?

Comment: after seeing your comment I tried myself to check to sample sdk and test using OpenTok The OpenTok Playground and its working fine. I compared my code with sample project and i found out following code I added

  do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.videoChat, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .allowBluetooth, .allowAirPlay])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
        }

Comment: if you add that to the sample does it also break the sample?

Comment: Thanks for the hint I tried and still it works fine. and also I tried to connect actual project with Vonage playground environment by passing hardcode apiKey ,sessionId and token even it still also. works  and did not loose audio

Comment: Any success in this scenario?

Comment: You guyz still  looking for a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue in our web application (using the JS SDK).

It turns out that our code is calling `subscribeToAudio` on the event `streamPropertyChanged`:

```
this.session.on('streamPropertyChanged', (e) => {
  if (e.changedProperty === 'hasAudio') {
    e.stream.subscriber.subscribeToAudio(e.newValue)
  }
})
```

Which is unnecessary and problematic, because:

1. `subscribeToAudio` affects only the local playback of audio, there's no point in calling it when the audio state of other participants is changing. Just let the SDK handle it.
2. When a Bluetooth device of a participant disconnects, it emits `streamPropertyChanged { hasAudio: false }` to all participants, but as it switches to the system default microphone it will not emit `{ hasAudio: true }`, and that's where the issue occurs

Removing this bit of code resolves the issue. Hope it helps.